# How to call event on formload drawitem

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, ondrawitem

I am using this code to put a image in listbox but the text does not show . When I click on the list then it shows . What is the problem ?

```
form_load()
{
   listbox1.Items.Add("string");
   listbox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
}

private void listbox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox lst = sender as ListBox;
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[0], 0, 0, 10, 10);
   e.Graphics.DrawString(lst.Text, this.Font,SystemBrushes.ControlDark, 11, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sure about the spelling of form_load ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're drawing your items incorrectly. `DrawItem` event is being called for each item in the listbox, but you're drawing all the times the same text at the same position. You should use `e.Bounds` to determine position of each item. Also you can handle `MeasureItem` event to set custom bounds for each item if you need some non-standard dimensions.

Also `lst.Text` doesn't has much sense here, it should be text of current item to draw, based on `e.Index`.

Thus, part of your code drawing string could look something like:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(lst.GetItemText(lst.Items[e.Index]), 
                      this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlDark, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
```

Also you may find useful some [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at MSDN.